# Delete default context menu when right click in CefSharp Chromium webbrowser with WPF

Tags: wpf, xamarin, wpf-controls, cefsharp

In my WPF Application, I am loading a URL in a CefSharp Webbrowser. When I gave rightclick from mouse, a default context menu is displaying as below image

[image]

My xaml code is

```
<Window x:Class="StoneApp.WebviewWindow" WindowState="Maximized"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StoneApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MyApp">

<DockPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="mygrid">
        <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="my_webview" IsBrowserInitializedChanged ="InitializeBrowser" Grid.Row="0" MouseRightButtonDown="Rightbtn_MouseDown"/>
    </Grid>

</DockPanel>

</Window>
```

My xaml.cs code is

```
  public WebviewWindow(string webresponse)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.webresponse = webresponse;
    }

    private void InitializeBrowser(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        my_webview.Load(webresponse);
    }

    private void Rightbtn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

When I give rightclick I am not able to call 'Rightbtn_MouseDown' function too. So my issue is I would like to delete/hide the default context menu when rightclick on the webbrowser view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to override the default `IContextMenuHandler`.

```
webView.MenuHandler = new MenuHandler();

internal class MenuHandler : IContextMenuHandler
{
    public bool IContextMenuHandler.RunContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model, IRunContextMenuCallback callback)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void IContextMenuHandler.OnBeforeContextMenu(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, IMenuModel model)
    {
        model.Clear();
    }
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Handlers/MenuHandler.cs